# Apostrophe breaks code written to output a shortcode

Tags: php, escaping, syntax-error, shortcode

Our client wanted a video and audio plug-in for the entertainment website, we found a nice looking one but the way you add items to the playlist was too confusing for our non technical clients.

We decided (budget had been largely spent by this point) to go with a plugin. We tried to build an ACF interface that allowed them to enter a title and URL of the file/video that reconstructed abd output the shortcode into a php template.

We had never done this before. It was hard. It took forever but finally we got it working! Great, we thought. Then the client used an apostrophe in the title of a video playlist item and it broke everything. Two other developers later about 6 hours of our time spent trying to solve this problem.... We are now at a loss on how to solve this issue...

Without the apostrophe = fine. With = video player fails to load.

We've been through illegal character, undefined character and various other issues of a similar nature.

The site http://fandf.ladesigns.co.uk/act/video/
The error https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufRNn.png

The Code:

```
$str2 = '[cleanvideoplayer playlist="';

                  foreach ($rows as $row) {

                                $str2 .= '{';

                                $title = $row['video_title'];
                                // $title = str_replace("'", "\'", $title);

                                $title = str_replace("'", "\'", $title);

                                $filetype = $row['file_type'];
                                $url = $row['url'];


                                $title2 = "title: '$title', ";
                                $url2 = "$filetype: '$url', ";

                                $str2 .= $title2;
                                $str2 .= $url2;

                                $str2 .= '},'; // added a comma here

                                // // $str2 = str_replace("'", '"', $str2);
                                // $str2 = str_replace('\"', "\'", $str2);

                                }

                     $str2 .= '"]';

                     // var_dump($str2);die();

                     }
                                // echo $str2;
                                echo do_shortcode( $str2 );
                                // echo cleanvideoplayer(); // Yey!

                            }
```